# When connected to Windows VPN and I do an nslookup it shows the DNS server's IP but name is unknown

Tags: windows-server-2003, vpn, rras

When I connect to my RRAS VPN I am having an issue where the VPN clients can ping/connect to servers by IP and their FQDN but not by their basic hostname.

When I did an nslookup on a VPN client it will show the proper DNS IP but the name of the server says Unknown.

Anybody know what could be causing this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to go into the VPN connection's settings, under TCP/IP's properties go to Advanced, then put the domain name in the box next to `DNS Suffix for this connection`

;-)

Comment: I realize I could do that on the client side, but isn't there a way to have that automatically configured when a VPN client connects?

Comment: The easiest way is to use CMAK : http://www.isaserver.org/img/upl/vpnkitbeta2/cmak.htm

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to configure RRAS to relay DHCP from your DHCP server, that way all the dns suffix's that you have configured locally would be propagated.

Routing and Remote Access -> server name -> IP Routing -> General 
Right-click *General*, and then click *New Routing Protocol*. 
In the Select Routing Protocol dialog box, click DHCP Relay Agent, and then click OK.

Edit that new DHCP Relay Agent object, and add the IP address of the DHCP server.

Then, Right-click on *server name* and select the IP tab, choose DHCP, ok!

Works a charm.

Answer (score 0):

i was facing the same problem. when i was connecting   corporate  vpn  non of resources was pinging, also nslookup was showing the dns ip but not Server name. i tried all the things but finally i got solution. client vpn software was creating the problem,after uninstalling the client  vpn software , i was able to access resources through vpn.

Answer (score -1):

That's normal. It means that there's no reverse lookup zone.

When you run nslookup, the DNS client tries to find the name of the DNS server that it's configured to use by sending a PTR query to that DNS server. If there's no reverse lookup zone (and therefore no PTR records) it gives the message that the server is uknown.

Reverse lookup zones are not required, so not having one won't do any harm.

Comment: Well I'm experiencing an issue where VPN clients aren't able to access machines by hostname so I thought maybe it had something to do with this. I can't seem to figure out how to get RRAS to give VPN clients the DNS suffix and WINS settings.

Comment: Ouch. A drive by downvote. I wish people would comment on their downvotes so that we'd at least have an opportunity to be educated on where we went wrong with our answers.